# Multiple case in c# 8.0 switch expression

Tags: c#-8.0

I am converting `switch statement` to `switch expression` but I don't do it. Where did my function go wrong?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't paste an image of your code, instead copy paste the code inline and format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or operator in switch is not available in c# 8.0, it is available c# 9.0 or greater versions, in c# 8.0 you may solve as following:

```
static string CardinalToOrdinal(int number)
        {
            return number switch
            {
                11 => $"{ number}th",
                12 => $"{ number}th",
                13 => $"{ number}th",
                _ => $"{number}" + number.ToString()[number.ToString().Length - 1]
                switch
                {
                    '1' => "st",
                    '2' => "nd",
                    _ => "th"
                }
            };
        }
```

For more information, pls look to [this](https://alexatnet.com/cs8-switch-statement/) article

Comment: Oh, yeah ,Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write your switch statement
2. Place your cursor in the `switch` keyword and press Ctrl+. to trigger the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu.
3. Select Convert switch statement to expression.

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/convert-switch-statement-to-switch-expression?view=vs-2019)

Happy Coding!

Comment: Sr.I run c# 8.0 visual studio code. So, i'm not Ctrl +. You knew different solve